# How do I use excel to keep stock of the number of products I have by automatically adding new stock and subtracting sales?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am selling cards and I want an easy way to keep stock of the number of each card I have. I want a column to contain the number of stock for a particular card, a second column where I input the amount of new stock I've acquired which will then automatically add itself onto my current stock number and then finally a third column where I input the amount of stock I've sold which will automatically subtract itself from my stock total.

For example I have 20 cards but then acquire 5 more, this is entered into the 'New Stock' column which is automatically added to the 'Current Stock' column to give 25 cards. I then sell 7 cards so I enter 7 into the 'Sales' column which automatically subtracts 7 from the 'Current Stock' column leaving 18 cards. Each time I add to the 'New Stock' or 'Sales' column I want the 'Current Stock' column to automatically update.

Comment: It would be helpful to see some sample data and the expected output. If needed, you can upload screencaps on [imgur.com](https://imgur.com/) and link to them here

Comment: In general, 1 sheet would be a transaction list to show additions/subtractions, and another sheet/pivot table to summarize into stock on hand.

Answer (score 0):

*You need to create a Stock & Inventory register, like I've show below, is the most popular & easiest method using the Excel.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in cell N86:

  `=(K86+L86)-M86`
- Use this formula in cell N87 & fill down till required:

  `=IF(AND(ISBLANK(L87),ISBLANK(M87)),"",(N86+L87)-M87)`

**N.B.** *You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*